# Generated Heatmap disappears after some time

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a matrix with 641x976 data points. To create a Heatmap I use the heatmap.2 function. I defined my own color palette and color breaks. In order to illustrate my problem I generate a random data set (data).
Here you can see my code:

```
data = replicate(976), rnorm(641)) 
 library(gplots)

my_palette = colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue"))(n = 299)

col_breaks = c(seq(-10, 0.2, length = 50), 
               seq(0.21, 1, length = 200), 
               seq(1.11, 10, length = 50))

heatmap.2(as.matrix(data), scale="none", col=my_palette,
          margins = c(1,1), Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
          breaks = col_breaks, dendrogram = "none", labRow = NULL, colRow = NULL, xlab = NULL,
          lmat = NULL, lhei = NULL, lwid = NULL, ylab = NULL)
```

The generated Heatmap disappears after some time and the channel gets light blue. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `data`?

Comment: Yes I just added a sample data set

Comment: Disappears from where?

Comment: From the "plots" window